# Facebook SDK login with Next.js and TS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, facebook, next.js

According to the [facebook documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/quickstart), I should use this code snippet after a `body` tag, but I tried that using `react-helmet` with no help

```js
export default function Test() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Helmet>
        <body>
          <script>
            window.fbAsyncInit = function(){' '}
            {FB.init({
              appId: 'your-app-id',
              autoLogAppEvents: true,
              xfbml: true,
              version: 'v8.0',
            })}
            ;
          </script>
          <script
            async
            defer
            crossorigin="anonymous"
            src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js"
          ></script>
        </body>
      </Helmet>
    </div>
  );
}
```

In addition, TS screams at me for using the `crossorigin` prop and having `FB` not declared anywhere.

There's also the issue of using `windows` with Next.js, where I should be using it inside `useEffect`, making things even more complicated.

If loggin with Next.js is not possible, how can I do it with a regular CRA?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: Saw this somewhere else. You can replace google script with your facebook script  here.
<script dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
                  __html: `
              window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
              function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
              gtag('js', new Date());
              gtag('config', '${GA_TRACKING_ID}', {
                page_path: window.location.pathname,
              });
          `
                }}
              />
https://medium.com/frontend-digest/using-nextjs-with-google-analytics-and-typescript-620ba2359dea